# How can I read a matrix from a txt file in R?

Tags: r

I have a txt file with a matrix

Matrix.txt(Important: There are no spaces between the numbers!):

```
0100
1001
1100
```

I want to read it in R as a matrix, how can I do that?

I tried with as.matrix(read.table("Matrix.txt", sep="")), but it failed, because every line will be read as one string, but not 4 characts. The `sep=""` doesn't work.

Comment: Please at least _glance_ at the manual on Data Import/Export _which came with your version of R_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One liner

```
as.matrix(read.fwf("Matrix.txt", widths = rep(1,4)))
```

Comment: This is far and away the best way I reckon.

Answer (score 2):

You can read as strings, then split the strings, convert to numeric, and bind to matrix.

```
dat <- readLines("Matrix.txt")
dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(dat, ""), as.numeric))
```